# How can a Haskell Async reliably run a cleanup action after an interrupt?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

For the sake of discussion, here's a brief example. It spawns an [`Async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Async) with 26 concurrent child `Async`s.

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Concurrent.Async (async, cancel, forConcurrently_)
import Control.Exception (finally)
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Prelude ((*), (*>), ($))
import System.IO (IO, hPutStr, stderr)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    a <- async $ forConcurrently_ ['a'..'z'] $ \c ->
        (print c *> delay 2) `finally` print (toUpper c)
    delay 1
    cancel a
  where
    delay sec = threadDelay (sec * 1000000)
    print c = hPutStr stderr [c]
```

Each child

1. Prints a letter (indicating that the process has begun)
2. Pauses
3. Using `finally`, should always end by printing the capital version of that letter (representing the "cleanup" action).

We then pause long enough for all of the `Async`s to start but not long enough for any of them to complete, and then call `cancel` on the parent, thus throwing an exception to each of the `Async`s.

I expected each `finally` action to run, producing the output

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

but instead I get

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC
```

How can I reason about what's going on in this example, and what's the correct way to get the sort of reliable cleanup behavior I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2):

What version of `async` are you using? The behavior of `cancel` changed in `2.1.1` to wait for the thread to actually exit. In earlier versions it just throws an asynchronous exceptions and exits. In your case, all threads received an exception, but not all had a chance to handle it (print the upper char) because `main` already exited. Try to add e.g. `delay 10` after `cancel`. If you are using `2.1.1`, then it may (or may not) indicate a bug in `async`.

ADDED: It indeed looks like a bug: https://github.com/simonmar/async/issues/59#issuecomment-289894612

Comment: I'm using async 2.1.1.

Comment: Yes, adding a delay at the end does fix it.

Comment: Then it is probably a bug. Documentation says nothing, but I think `forConcurrently` in `2.1.1` should wait for all children to actually exit. IMO you should at report it.